# How to update android application with different namespace from the precedent on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, package-name

I have already a published application in Google Play and I would like to change its name?
Is this possible and how?

Comment: In your question title, you use "namespace". In your question body, you use "name". These are different concepts. Please consider editing your question to be *very precise* about what you wish to change.

Answer (score 2):

if you are referring to the application's unique package name as defined in the manifest, no, it's not possible.

this is how the play store, other stores like amazon's, and devices agree to identify an app. if you change it, the stores could no longer understand that the app in the store is the same as the app on your device. well, i suppose they could support some sort of aliasing, but they do not.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name that is shown under the icon on the device but you can't change the package name.  The package name (com.example.android.etc) is how the Google Play Store tells the apps apart so it would think that they are two completely different apps and would not allow you to upload that as an update.